# How can I execute a shell command in a child process in Python?

Tags: python, shell, pipe, multiprocessing

I need to use the multiprocessing module (rather than subprocess, as I need to use pipes) to execute a shell command as a new child process. At the moment I'm using:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(subprocess_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=parent_env)
```

where `subprocess_command` is a shell command (it runs a Python script with arguments) and `parent_env` is the current environment with an environmental variable (LD_PRELOAD) set differently. What would be the equivalent using the multiprocessing module? The child process (Python script) needs to be able to pipe back to the parent.

Comment: ummm you dont really do this with multiprocessing ... typically ... multiprocessing is for calling methods in your script ... I think subprocess.Popen is not bound to the GIL in quite the same way if thats what you are worried about ...

Comment: Thanks Joran. I should have written why I'm trying to do this - basically the reason I'm looking at creating a child process is so that it can have a different library of C functions preloaded (hence LD_PRELOAD). I don't know of any way to have a subprocess started with Popen communicate back to its parent during execution, which is why I'm looking at the multiprocessing module.

Comment: you can certainally get feedback from the method

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I just looked into subprocess.poll() and subprocess.stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will demonstrate how to get streaming output back from a Popen

**file1.py**

```
import time,os
while True:
    print "OK ?"+os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"]
    time.sleep(1)
```

**file2.py**

```
import os
os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = "5"
p = subprocess.Popen(subprocess_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=os.environ)
p.start()
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
   print line
   time.sleep(0.6)
```